# Joining multiple dataframes and duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure i'm doing something wrong but it's not obvious to me.

I have many dataframes which i want to join. I'm joining using pd.merge left joins i do this as

```
Database=pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='key', Right_on='key',how='left')

Database=pd.merge(df3, df4, left_on='key', Right_on='key',how='left')
```

Repeating but always writing back to the database dataframe, all works fine but at the end i have multiple duplicates, ie df1_code has been repeated as df1_code_x, df1_code_x_x which is making the resultant df very large. I attempted;

```
Database.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

but this caused a cms memory error, how can i stop the columns duplicating to start with.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid having the duplicates, at least not by means of using `pd.merge` with any arguments.

`pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` seem to be working in dropping duplicate rows. That explains why you are transposing and the trying `drop_duplicates`. Might be an idea to use it after each merge rather than once at the end?

Also, according to your sample calls, you don't really need to define both `right_on` and `left_on` arguments. Both seem to be the same so you can save yourself the typing and tun this to:

```
Database = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='key')
Database = df3.merge(df4, how='left', on='key')
...
```

I hope that helps